# ID of Apache Beam Window Session

Tags: java, session, apache-beam

I am gathering `TableRows` into apache beam [session windows](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#session-windows) and want to add each row some kind of a session id after its session is determined.

This code does the partition to sessions:

```
PCollection<TableRow> rows = ...; // "rows" looks like {{"id":1}, {"id":2}, {"id":3}}
PCollection<TableRow> sessionWindowedRows = rows.apply(
    Window.<TableRow>into(Sessions.withGapDuration(Duration.standardSeconds(300))));
```

And I want something like that:

```
PCollection<TableRow> rows = ...; // "rows" looks like {{"id":1}, {"id":2}, {"id":3}}
PCollection<TableRow> sessionWindowedRows = rows.apply(
    Window.<TableRow>into(Sessions.withGapDuration(Duration.standardSeconds(300))))
    .apply("adding session id to table row", ParDo.of(new DoFn<TableRow, TableRow>() {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext ctx) {
            TableRow row = ctx.element();
            row.put("sessionId", Sessions.getSessionOf(row); // Sessions.getSessionOf(row) IS NOT A REAL FUNCTION
            ctx.output(row);
        }
}));
```

So at last `rows` will look like

```
{{"id":1, "sessionId":lastSessionId1}, {"id":2, "sessionId":lastSessionId2}, {"id":3, "sessionId":lastSessionId3}}
```

The best I found was this apache beam [docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/custom-windows) about custom windows but I couldn't understand from it how to do what I want.

Comment: Any reason you are adding the window? If you are not aggregating the window is not applied. For the session window you need a KV, and the key is used to measure the gaps

Comment: @Iñigo I used the example from here https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#using-session-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `@ProcessElement` function you can define a parameter of type [BoundedWindow](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.35.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/BoundedWindow.html). From that you can get `maxTimestamp()` of the element's assigned window; and thus create a sessionId from that.

```
@ProcessElement
public void processElement(ProcessContext ctx, BoundedWindow window) {
    TableRow row = ctx.element();
    row.put("sessionId", "session_" + window.maxTimestamp().toString());
    ctx.output(row);
}
```

I second Iñigo's assertion that you don't need a session window (or any window) unless you are aggregating. I presume that happens elsewhere in your pipeline?

Comment: That's a great help! Is there any way to get the minTimestamp of the window instead of the max?

Comment: To answer my last comment here I used `IntervalWindow` instead of `BoundedWindow` and then set the sessionId to be `intervalWindow.start().toString()`. Do you know if it will give same value for early firing panes of the same session?